# AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL error for linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to make a linked list in C where it reads from an input file and either adds or deletes nodes. I'm getting an AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL error (pictured) which I think is from dereferencing a null pointer in my insert node function, but I cannot find where I do that. If I am wrong on what this error means, or you see where I am going wrong that would be a ton of help. Thanks so much!!

'''

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
} Node;

void printList(Node *head){
  Node *temp = head->next;
  int count;
  while(temp != NULL){
    temp = temp->next;
    count++;
  }
  printf("%d\n", count);
  temp = head->next;
  while(temp != NULL){
    printf("%d\t", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}

Node *makeNode(int value){
  Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  newNode->data = value;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  return newNode;
}

void insertNode(Node *head, Node *newNode){
  Node *temp ,*prev;
  temp = head;
  while(temp != NULL && temp->data <= newNode->data) {
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  newNode->next = temp;
  prev->next = newNode;
}

void deleteNode(Node *head, int deleteNum){
  if(head->next != NULL){
    if(head->next->data == deleteNum){
      head->next = head->next->next;
      free(head->next);
    }
    else{
      //printf("hello");
      Node *temp ,*prev;
      temp = head;
      while(temp != NULL && temp->data != deleteNum) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
      }
      if(temp != NULL){
        prev->next = temp->next;
        //free(temp);
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Node* head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  Node *temp;
  char* filename = argv[1];
  if(fopen(filename, "r") == NULL){
    printf("error");
  }
  else{
  FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  char mode;
  int tempData;

  while (fscanf(fp, "%c\t%d\n", &mode, &tempData ) == 2) {
    //printf("%c\n", mode);
    if(mode == 'i'){
      //printf("%c\n", 'i');
      Node *insert = makeNode(tempData);
      insertNode(head, insert);
    }
    else if(mode == 'd'){
      //printf("%c\n", 'd');
      //printList(head);
      deleteNode(head, tempData);
      //printList(head);
    }
  }
  printList(head);
}
}
```

'''
[image: Picture of error]

Comment: Can you provide input that triggers the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialize the node that `head` points to in `main`, so when you pass it to `insertNode`, the value of `head->next` may be garbage; in particular it may not be NULL.  In that case the `while` loop will run at least two iterations, setting `temp` to the garbage pointer `head->next`, and the access of `temp->data` in the condition of the `while` will dereference that garbage pointer.  Hence the crash.

You probably want `head->next = NULL;` somewhere in `main`, after the `malloc` but before the `insertNode`.   Or better still, use your existing `makeNode` function to allocate `head`.

There is another bug in that you also never initialize `head->data`, which is compared against `newNode->data`.  If the garbage in `head->data` is greater than `newNode->data`, `insertNode` will attempt to insert it in the list prior to `head`, which won't work and will simply result in the node being lost.  Moreover `prev` will be used uninitialized, which will probably also crash.  You could work around by initializing `head->data` to `INT_MIN`, but it would be better to fix the logic of `insertNode` so that it never compares against `head->data` in the first place.  `deleteNode` has a similar issue.

One more bonus bug: `count` is uninitialized in `printList`.

You could have found the latter bugs by compiling with `-Wall -O`; gcc will then detect and warn about uninitialized variables.  `valgrind` also detected the `printList` bug for me.